# Is Rey's instant bread real technology?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology, food

I thought this has been asked before but couldn't find it.

In the movie, Rey first scenes included one where she just added water to a pile of powder and *poof* it transforms into bread.

Out of curiosity, is this a kind of newfangled technology that is already reality on Earth or in the process of becoming so?

**Edit**: I don't think McDonald's powdered scrambled eggs count...don't troll ok?

Comment: Sidenote: Would it have been a good or bad idea if that had been instant sandwich instead?

Comment: Not a dupe. I'm not looking for in or out of universe explanations of what Rey's meal is. I'm asking if such a thing exists on Earth.

Comment: (On second reading, I redraw my comment that this question is answered in the duplicate).

Answer (score 3):

While I can't believe I'm posting this as the source for your answer, here's an article that talks about it: http://www.mtv.com/news/2728173/star-wars-rey-bread/

The technology was a real thing, and did work. NASA has also been working on a solution for this for a while, if they haven't already made it.

Comment: That link only confirms it's not CGI, but it didn't confirm it's an *edible* effect. Do you have links from NASA? By real technology, I meant it in the sense of real food, not practical vs CGI.

Comment: Sorry, bit of clarification. The article does mention that while it is edible, it wouldn't taste good: "But in case you’re one of those people clamoring for a home version of Rey’s food portions, don’t get too excited — the bread might have been a real practical effect, but it also tasted terrible and probably had next to no real nutritional value." However, if it does help, while it's not exactly the same, there is quick-ready food they use mostly based off military MRE's: https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/apollo-to-the-moon/online/astronaut-life/food-in-space.cfm

Comment: @sgt_ginger - I think you may be mistaking the inflatable prop used for the effect with the (edible) prop bread that Rey eats later in the scene.

Comment: Please read the article. It clearly states that while it is a prop, it can be eaten. That being said, if you're all looking for good tasting edible instant bread, that answer is likely no.